# MySQL - how to match JSON string in where condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6 , one of my table field contains JSON data. I am getting syntax error when using below query -

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE device_id = '1212'and product_id = '54'and option = '"{"229":"20"}"'
```

field **option** has value as `{"229":"20"}` I am getting following error -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option = '"{"229":"20"}"'
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Please suggest any solution , thanks much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`option` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Use backticks to escape it or choose a different name

```
... `option` = ...
```